# How do I take data from one screen and add it to a UIView on another screen?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm fairly new to app development, and I've tried to find solutions to this but haven't been able to.

I'm trying to develop a to-do app, with the main feature being that the tasks are displayed as cards. I want it to be something like [this](https://vimeo.com/239386409), but the animation will come later. I'm stuck on figuring out how to take the data given by the user and add it on a card to the main screen.

[Here's what I want to achieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whStQ.png)

How would I add a new view with the data related to the task, for however many tasks the user has? I don't even need the card behind to be smaller at this point, I want the basic functionality done. The data comes from a different screen, where the user can add (for now) a name and priority.

Lastly, I want the next task to be shown when the user swipes, so right now I don't think it matters that there needs to be more than one card at a time, the data just needs to be updated with the next task.

This is the code I have for the New Task screen:

```
import UIKit

class NewTaskVC: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func cancelButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var newTaskName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var newTaskDescription: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
        return UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
    }

    @IBAction func addTask(_ sender: Any) {
    }

}
```

How would I accomplish at least a part of this if not all of it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a model that stores the list of tasks, and some way of persisting it.
2. Create another view controller to represent each card. It will refer to one task, and its viewDidLoad will populate its UI from the task.
3. In NewTaskVC, iterate over the model's tasks and create an instance of the card vc for each task. Add each instance as a child view controller of NewTaskVC, and add auto layout constraints for the child view constrollers' views. When you create each instance, pass it a reference to the task it is to display data for.

That's a very high level. Your question is broad. You may want to seek out some samples. Good luck.